# Install Ruby and Rails on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian-squeeze, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We have a Linux (Debian Squeeze) server in production, currently running apps on a LAMP stack.

I now need to bring over an existing RoR app from a different server onto this new server and get it running. I've seen Ror installation scripts on GIT that include an Apache server so more geared towards installation on a clean box.

What's the installation path for Ruby 1.9/Rails 3 on a Debian Squeeze server currently running Apache2?

Is there a recommended installation tutorial someplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a recommended tutorial.

Since the system-provided ruby for Squeeze is a [Ruby1.8](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ruby), your Ruby 1.9 install will not be able to use system-ruby. You'll have to install 1.9 some other way, probably via [rvm](https://rvm.io/). At this point you're out of the land of "RoR on DebSqueeze" and into the land of "RoR on Apache on Linux", which is a much better documented problem.

To get RoR running you'll need:

- An RVM install somewhere
- The 'passenger' gem installed
- The 'rails' gem installed
- Apache configured to load the mod_passenger.so file from the gem
- Apache configured to launch

So stop looking for deb-specific scripts/installers, and start looking for more generic ones. They're out there.

Answer (score 1):

you can install phusion-passenger and use Apache2 as web server using mod-proxy, ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, it's very easy the setup in a VirtualHost

only type this lines into VirtualHost:

```
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:port/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:port/
```

With this you will have configured your Apache server

also enables the mods for proxy into Apache Server

Good Day.

Juan Trejo